# Throw an error from an OpenEdge UI trigger to the main program

Tags: triggers, progress-4gl, openedge, throw

I'm struggling to propagate an system error object from a UI trigger to the main program.

```
  ON CHOOSE OF btnButton IN FRAME frmFrame
  DO:

     /* this will cause a system error */
     FIND FIRST Customer NO-LOCK
          WHERE Customer.CustNum = 1875918759178.

     CATCH eErr AS Progress.Lang.SysError:
        /* It does get caught over here */
        UNDO, THROW eErr.
     END CATCH.
  END.

  CATCH eMain AS Progress.Lang.SysError:
     /* this message doesn't happen */
     MESSAGE
        "caught"
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
  END CATCH.
```

It doesn't seem to want to propagate the error object though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on THROW option, Undo Statement:

"UNDO, THROW is not allowed in a CATCH block of a user interface trigger. The ABL does not you to raise or RETURN error out of a user interface trigger. To do so will result in a compile-time error. "
The sentence above says "Does not you to..." I believe it should be "does not allow you to". But the documentation itself is wrong.

Anyway, it seems what you're trying to accomplish is not yet possible as of today (Dec,27,2016).

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I can come up with something to make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NO-ERROR on the end of the FIND statement:

```
FIND FIRST Customer NO-LOCK
      WHERE Customer.CustNum = 1875918759178 NO-ERROR.
```

Then you can use the ERROR-STATUS system handle to catch the error:

```
MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:ERROR SKIP
        ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1)
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

That error status should be set until some other statement executes with NO-ERROR. You can also use AVAILABLE(Customer) to see if the record was found:

```
MESSAGE AVAILABLE(Customer) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: Thank you. Usually I would use a FIND statement with the NO-ERROR option. Then test it with an ERROR-STATUS:ERROR or AVAILABLE(). In this particular case I'm forcing a case where a system error can happen in order to test how the program handles it. It's passing the error object from the UI trigger to the containing procedure

Comment: You might have better luck moving the trigger code to a procedure. If the error happens you can pass that back as a parameter to the trigger, avoiding the problem of using `UNDO, THROW` in a trigger.